# Javascript: Printing the statement line by line when we have a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

We have 5 statements in a line and If we have a set timeout in the 3 statement it will executed after all the remaining statement got executed. I'm looking to execute the each statement line by line even If we have a set timeout in-between the code.

Example:
We have some statements

```js
console.log("A");
setTimeout(console.log("B"), 1000);
console.log("C");
```

The expected output is **A C B** but I want to print is a **A B C**.
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Actually that _will_ print A B C.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OP expects it to print ACB

Comment: You made the common mistake of not passing a function _reference_ to setTimeout, but you put a function _call_ there. The `console.log("B")` executes immediately, and its return value (which does not really exist), is what setTimeout would try to "execute" 1000ms later. You need to wrap this into an anonymous function - `setTimeout(function() { console.log("B"); }, 1000);`

Comment: @mplungjan _"I want to print is a A B C"_

Comment: The question doesn't make sense right now. Even if the mistake with how `setTimeout` is called, you *cannot* make an asynchronous operation complete in synchronous manner in order with other synchronous operations. You can hack around how `setTimeout` works to "disable" the asynchronicity but that's hardly a useful approach for whatever real task you're trying to solve. Simply put what you ask is not possible and practical at the same time. I heavily suspect this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) hiding the real issue to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your setTimout was incorrect since it WILL execute the console.log immediately.

Assuming I understood correctly, tTo do what you want, you need to replace console and setTimeout

```js
const myMessages = [];
const myConsole = window.console;
window.console = { log: (str) => myMessages.push(`mine: ${str}`) }
const myTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = func => {
  myMessages.push(func)
};
console.log("A");
setTimeout(() => console.log("B"), 1000);
console.log("C");
window.console = myConsole; // reset
myMessages.forEach(msg => {
  if (typeof msg === "string") console.log(msg)
  else msg()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the timeouts, something like this (treat this as a proof of concept, but it is tested)

```js
var linesToPrint = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

function WriteNextLine(lineCount) {
  if (linesToPrint[lineCount] != undefined) {
    console.log(linesToPrint[lineCount]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      WriteNextLine(++lineCount);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
WriteNextLine(0);
```

Comment: I think they want the text to come in order REGARDLESS of a timeout. Your code just added all to the timeout

Comment: no, this code ensures they come in order at whatever interval. They are output one at a time, in this case at one second intervals. The first one only is immediately output, but this can be easily changed. If you want them to come out all at the same time but in the right order then just go through the array.

Comment: I know what your code does. I do not think that is what OP asked though

Comment: I was assuming "execute the each statement line by line" referred to console.log("A");, console.log("B");, console.log("C");

Comment: OP: `I'm looking to execute the each statement line by line even If we have a set timeout in-between the code.` so `console.log("A"); setTimeout(() => console.log("B"),1000); console.log("C");` should output A,B,C

Comment: This will print ACB, unlike their original code which will print ABC (as has been explained). Their use of "the expected output ... ACB" and "I want to print .. ABC" is confusing for this reason.